# Rearrange rows in ASP.NET Table without recreating Table

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET Table. All of its rows and cells are created dynamically with various controls etc. I want the ability to be able to reorder the rows, without recreating the entire table. Is this possible in C#, ASP.NET.

I can't create a `DataTable` and then use it as a `DataSource` for a `Gridview` and then rearrange the rows that way because I have controls and nested `Tables` in the main table.

Is this possible at all? Any one have any suggestions?

The reason I need to be able to do this is because of time and performance issues.

Comment: Forgoing the use of a `DataTable` aside, it still seems that ordering your data *before* creating the UI from it would still be the way to go.

Comment: We do but then we give the user the ability to reorder it. It is a production line. At the moment it has to recreate the whole table every time and is incredibly slow.

Comment: If the table already exists client-side and the user is re-ordering it in the browser, maybe apply some JavaScript to let the user re-order without posting back to the server at all?  There are a variety of plugins (mostly jQuery of course) which provide rich table functionality, many of which can just apply on top of an existing HTML table structure.  It wouldn't be much effort to roll one's own sort functionality in JavaScript either.  Not a quick fix per se, but perhaps worth the time given the overall performance problems.